# Specify Author with Microformats

Tags: microformats

I would like to make the author of a page appear in Google Rich Snippets.

Is it possible to do that with Microformats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the ["People" microformat documentation for Google Rich Snippets](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146646). Here's the [overview of how the snippets work](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html). After filling in the vCard, make sure to [submit it to Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/request.py?contact_type=rich_snippets_feedback) so it gets picked up.

Note that it's still an experimental feature and it appears they're mostly focusing on reviews and social networking, so you're not at all assured that they'll display the vCard you add, or will know that it's the page author. But it's easy enough to add.

Sample (from the documentation above):

```
<div class="vcard">
<div class="fn">John Smith</div>
<span class="nickname">Smithy</span>
<span class="url">http://www.example.com</span>
<span class="org">ACME</span>
<span class="adr">
 <span class="locality">Albuquerque</span>
</span>
<span class="title">Engineer</span>
<a href="http://darryl-blog.example.com/" rel="friend">Darryl</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's guidelines seems to be better when you use rel=”author” authorship declaration. Highly recommended in the case of news websites, blogs, or opinion sites (http://www.kozelben.hu/)...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's only done for [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.co.uk/intl/en/scholar/about.html) and there's no other way yet.